# Out of memory when downloading a file

Tags: android, download, out-of-memory

```
HttpResponse responseGet;
        try {
            responseGet = client.execute(get);
            switch (responseGet.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()) {
            case 200:
                File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File directory = new File(SDCardRoot
                        + "/OfflineDocuments/"
                        + (document.getPath() == null ? ""
                                : (document.getPath() + "/")));
                directory.mkdirs();
                File file = new File(directory, fileName);
                InputStream is = responseGet.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

                ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
                int current = 0;
                while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                    baf.append((byte) current);
                }

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
                fos.close();
                break;

            default:
                Log.e("Statuscode", "Unexpected status code: "
                        + responseGet.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
                break;
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This works for small documents. But for documents larger than a few MB this code crashes with "OutOfMemoryException". Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're slurping the file into memory in its entirety, then you write that buffered file out to storage. Instead, skip the buffering and write the pieces to storage as they come in.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
    fos.write(current);
}
fos.close();
```

note... not an android developer, so no idea if this would actually work, so treat this as pseudo-code.

Comment: Your solution slows down the app very hard because every single byte is written. I changed it that way, that I summarize 1MB, write these at once, and start again caching 1MB. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You are simply trying to read the whole file into memory and your JVM has not enough memory available. You probably want to write to the file inside your while loop rather than appending it to the buffer.